# Keep non duplicated values from a row in R

Tags: r

I searching for a solution that I couldn't find on Stackoverflow. 
I have a data frame with milions of rows that looks like this:

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
|       session        |            session_b             |     A     |     B     |     C     |     D     |  
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
| 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 | e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451 | 588238268 | 587606411 | 581149505 | 581149505 |  
| 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 | e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451 | 591266911 | 591257117 | 568939090 | 587606411 |  
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
```

My goal is to check from A to D for duplicated values for every row. If there is a duplicated value I would like to keep the non duplicated values. Below the result for the upper table.

```
+----------------------+----------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+--------+---
|       session        |            session_b            |     A     |     B    |     C     |     D     |  
+----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------
| 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 | e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451| 588238268 | 587606411|                       |  
| 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 | e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451| 591266911 | 591257117| 568939090 | 587606411 |  
+----------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------
```

Comment: Do you need `df1[c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')] <- t(apply(df1[c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')], 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE), NA)))`

Comment: almost, look at the first row, I delete the duplication. Your code removes the second occurence.

Comment: Perhaps you looked at the code before the edit

Comment: you can check my solution below which shows exactly as the expected output.  Here, I use `NA` instead of blanks

Comment: Perfect! There is a comma missing before c but its working! Many thanks :).

Comment: Is there any faster method I could use? I have 7M rows so it takes many minutes to finish :/

Comment: there are options to reshape into 'long' format and then do it, but it may also have issues in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to replace all the duplicates, use `duplicated` by row with `apply` and `MARGIN = 1`

```
df1[c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')] <- t(apply(df1[c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')], 1, 
   function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE), NA)))


df1
#               session                        session_b         A         B         C         D
#1 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451 588238268 587606411        NA        NA
#2 162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8 e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451 591266911 591257117 568939090 587606411
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(session = c("162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8", "162f2f8f7c5x8f6de8f8"
), session_b = c("e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451", "e5c44c77b9cae93afa9457e535c81451"
), A = c(588238268L, 591266911L), B = c(587606411L, 591257117L
), C = c(581149505L, 568939090L), D = c(581149505L, 587606411L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: For saving into data frame I added as.data.frame, its working :).

Comment: @Michel With `df1[c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')] <- `, the attributes of ddata.frame are still there.  You don't need the `as.data.frame`